# asp .net request won't parse to model int property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, parsing

I implemented my requests with complex types and string properties just fine. Now I added an id as `long` and my request returned a `400` ErrorCode. It turned out, that the problem vanishes when I'm changing my id to a string.
This is my code:

```
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult<User> Put(User updatedUser)
{
...
}
...
...
...
    public class User : IUser
    {
        [JsonProperty("userid")]
        public long UserId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
     ...
    }
```

This is how a request json is being received by my server:
`"{"Userid":"1337","Username":"test","Password":"admin"}"`

Obviously I want to parse this id to a long value.

Comment: Did you provide the userId in the request?. Maybe the your getting the BadRequest because a long can't be null.

Comment: Yes I did provide it in the request, and it also parses correctly, when my userid property is a string.

Comment: Please provide an example of the JSON that is being sent to the Controller that isn't de-serializing properly.

Comment: I've extended the question with the JSON @peinearydevelopment

Comment: `"Userid": "1337"` is a string, not a JSON `number`. Use `"Userid": 1337` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I missed that one